# Handling core dumps when holding boost::interprocess shared memory lock

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess

I am working on application where several multi-threaded processes are attempting to acquire a lock on the shared memory files managed via boost::interprocess (scoped_lock on named_mutex).

It appears that if one of these processes dumps a core while holding a lock on the shared memory file, all the other processes end up waiting for this lock to be released.

Any ideas on how this can be overcome? I want to ensure that when a process that is holding the lock dies, it should ensure that the lock is released.

One problem I see is that I am not invoking the destructor of the named_mutex object. Could this be the cause of this issue? Is the destructor guaranteed to be called when the process core dumps?

Thanks!

Comment: No. destructor won't be called when the process core dumps. I don't think there is a reliable way to solve this problem.

Comment: The best you can do is try to handle certain signals and exceptions, so that even in the absolute worst case you can do some minimal cleanup before you crash. Unfortunately, if you've got to this point, the state of your program is probably already too messed up to do anything. Of course what you really need to do is work out why it cores, and stop it.